# can any context free grammar be recognized by a non deterministic pushdown automaton?

Tags: specifications, computation-theory

can any context free grammar be recognized by a non deterministic pushdown automaton? im really not sure about this, I think that context free grammers can

Answer (score 1):

Pushdown automata do not recognize context-free grammars, but context-free languages. The language of any context-free grammar can be recognized by some nondeterministic pushdown automaton, though. This is probably what you meant to ask.

To see this, imagine a nondeterministic pushdown automaton that functions as follows. It begins by pushing the start symbol of the grammar onto the stack. Then, it pops the topmost symbol and nondeterministically replaces nonterminal symbols by choosing some available production rule. If it pops a terminal symbol, it consumers that symbol from the input stream. It accepts if the stack is empty and the input is exhausted.

The nondeterministic PDA just described pushes for any input string a derivation of that string, if any, according to the grammar for the language. This should show that a nondeterministic PDA can accept any language generated by a CFG.

Answer (score 0):

[ i have used the terms context free grammar and context free language interchangeably ]
I think your question is posed this way.Can a non-deterministic push down automaton accept any  context free languages.

Nondeterministic push down automaton accepts only one unique language that is unique to it. there is no guarantee that they accept all the context free languages out there.

OR

if your question is can "a" context free language  be recognised by "a" non-deterministic push down automaton.then the answer is yes .. because a language being context free means that there is a push down automaton or  non-deterministic push down automaton that accepts it .